# Multiple .string files of same language inside project

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have an IOS project that has a es.lproj folder with a string file inside it. Now within the project I have a sub project (feedback system) that has its own es.lproj folder with a string file inside.

The problem is that the app when testing is choosing to translate the text based upon only one of the string files and is ignoring the other.

I want to keep the localisation for the feedback system separate so is it possible to have two of the same language files within the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` instead of `NSLocalizedString`.

In your subproject, specify a table name for all of your strings.

I have a larger project with about 20 strings files using this approach.

You will probably need to use the `genstrings` command-line tool to generate the strings files from your code.